# How to add social sharing to fancybox (fancybox3) toolbar as seen in demo?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, sharing, fancybox-3

On the fancybox3 deme page (https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) you can configure options to show a share button as part of the toolbar.

[screenshot of demo sharing option enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuvor.png)

[screenshot of working fancybox demo with sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUAky.png)

However, when I add the following buttons option code, as outlined in the documentation, no such sharing button is included.

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    buttons : [
        'share',
        'fullScreen',
        'close'
    ]
})
```

How can I add the same social sharing feature as shown in the demo? If that's shown as an option, and included in the documentation as an option (with no additional instructions or special requirements mentioned), I'm assuming it's something built-in to fancybox3? If not, is there an easy way to recreate this?

I've seen questions and fiddles showing how this is done for older versions of fancybox, but only need input on how this is to be done in the latest version, fancybox 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your selector `$('[data-fancybox]')` returns your items, it should work fine. Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReRwLP?editors=1010